# Keycloak - "Client secret not provided in request" error

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

Looking for a solution to Unauthorized response from Keycloak server.
On the first time the login is finished successfully, and I got the KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY data into the cookie and i can see the connection on Keycloak admin page.
Then the KeycloakService is making another request to 'http://localhost:4000/realms/imisight-app/protocol/openid-connect/token' with the cookie to get the rest necessary data and tokens.
but this request returning 401 with error message - "Client secret not provided in request".

On Keycloak docs there is no mention to the 'ClientSecret' and where to provide it.
Does anyone know what to do?

Using angular v.14, keycloak v.19, keycloak-angular v.12

look on DOCS, tried to change Keycloak admin page data [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBVeX.png)

Comment: This happens when you try to login via Browser ?

Comment: yes, happening on chrome

Comment: just use a public client instead of a confidential one